# How to share resources without exposing Rc in the API?

Tags: rust, reference-counting

I'm working on a geometry crate and I thought in order for things to work nicely I should use `Rc` when referencing shared points. For example:

```rust
struct Point {
    point: Vec4,
}

struct Line {
    points: [Rc<Point>; 2],
}

struct Tri {
    points: [Weak<Point>; 3],
    edges: [Rc<Line>; 3],
}

struct Tetra {
    points: [Weak<Point>; 4],
    edges: [Weak<Line>; 6],
    faces: [Rc<Tri>; 4],
}
```

This makes sense as it seems to be the most efficient way to keep track of the components of a simplex. The problem is in the API. I don't want to expose this `Rc` internal, and I'd like it if I can just pass references in. For example, something like this:

```rust
let points = [Point::new(p0), Point::new(p1), Point::new(p2), Point::new(p3)];
let tris = [
    Tri::new(&points[0], &points[1], &points[2]),
    Tri::new(&points[2], &points[3], &points[0])
];
```

Etc. Without the user having to explicitly deal with `Rc` themselves.

What sort of pattern do we typically see here?

Comment: Do you *need* them all to be shared references? Are you planning to mutate them in-place? In my mind, it makes way more sense for a `Line` to have sole ownership over two `Point`s. Depending on what `Vec4` is, you may even be able to get away with `Point : Copy` so that moving them around is even more convenient.

Comment: There may be other assumptions here that are also not immediately obvious.  For example, with 4 points, I can make 6 lines and 4 triangles from those same 4 vertices.  So this may be non-trivial, and their model may be what they need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want resources to be shared without the user managing the `Rc`s themselves, you create your internal structure as normal and create wrappers around the `Rc`s for your public interface.

Keep your structure as-is but preferably with a naming scheme indicating that they're internal (often `Inner` or `Impl` suffixed):

```
struct PointInner {
    point: Vec4,
}

struct LineInner {
    points: [Rc<PointInner>; 2],
}

struct TriInner {
    points: [Weak<PointInner>; 3],
    edges: [Rc<LineInner>; 3],
}

struct TetraInner {
    points: [Weak<PointInner>; 4],
    edges: [Weak<LineInner>; 6],
    faces: [Rc<TriInner>; 4],
}
```

Then create your user-facing types that are just wrappers around the `Rc`s with a nice facade dealing with the links internally (you can use an `inner` field as I've done or use [new type structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html)):

```
pub struct Point {
    inner: Rc<PointInner>,
}

pub struct Line {
    inner: Rc<LineInner>,
}

pub struct Tri {
    inner: Rc<TriInner>,
}

pub struct Tetra {
    inner: Rc<TetraInner>,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(point: Vec4) -> Point {
        Point {
            inner: Rc::new(PointInner { point }),
        }
    }
}

impl Tri {
    pub fn new(p1: &Point, p2: &Point, p3: &Point) -> Tri {
        Tri {
            inner: Rc::new(TriInner {
                points: [
                    Rc::downgrade(&p1.inner),
                    Rc::downgrade(&p2.inner),
                    Rc::downgrade(&p3.inner),
                ],
                edges: [
                    Rc::new(LineInner {
                        points: [Rc::clone(&p1.inner), Rc::clone(&p2.inner)],
                    }),
                    Rc::new(LineInner {
                        points: [Rc::clone(&p2.inner), Rc::clone(&p3.inner)],
                    }),
                    Rc::new(LineInner {
                        points: [Rc::clone(&p3.inner), Rc::clone(&p1.inner)],
                    }),
                ],
            }),
        }
    }
}
```

With this your desired code works without changes. See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8fb5f90e1b1b340196e8ddef260d0a75).